# Как добавить метод с аргументами в поток

Tags: c#

Всем здравствуйте, Есть метод. 
Есть поток FileStream, как можно добавить этот метод  ADD_Block_to_Queue в другой поток. При этом чтобы и стримовый поток работал

```
  using (var fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open))// открываем поток

      ADD_Block_to_Queue(queue_block,fs);// сам метод, принимает два аргумента.
```

Comment: Ничего не понятно. Вероятно, речь о разных потоках: thread и stream?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Да речь о разных потоках мне нужен поток thread чтобы в нем работал метод мой в аргументе которого есть поток stream

Answer (score 0):

Такой вариант не подходит?

```
using (var fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open))
{
   var addingThread = new Thread(()=>ADD_Block_to_Queue(queue_block,fs));
   addingThread.Start();
}
```

Comment: Да такой вариант может подойти, а как себя будет вести поток который stream, если я поток  остановлю или усыплю, для проверки чего нибудь?

Comment: @VladimrVladimirovoch ну по идее останется в том же состоянии в котором был на момент остановки / усыпления

Comment: Увы, но stream при такой конструкции не работает, ексепшен вылетает

Comment: @VladimrVladimirovoch ну да, вам нужно подождать пока тред отработает, а уже потом уничтожать `fs`. Попробуйте после строки со стартом потока добавить `addingThread.Join();`